# Spring Boot with themeleaf not able to access css on HTML file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Technology : Spring Boot with themeleaf

I'm trying to access the css file placed under src/main/resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css  on my HTML using the following code:

But it is not loading.

Folder Structure :

Resources

--->assets

------>vendor

--------->bootstrap

------------>css

--------------->bootstrap.css

--->code

Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @sirandy:
 HTML Code

<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
 th:href="@{assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css} "/>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 th:href="@{assets/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
 th:href="@{assets/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css}" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my spring security config,

```
    http.
             csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home/**", "/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/public/rest/**","/login*","/signin/**","/signup/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/property/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/welcome/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic().disable();
```

Simply you need this line,

```
  .antMatchers("/home/**", "/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/public/rest/**","/login*","/signin/**","/signup/**").permitAll()
```

But, I would suggest to disable security first and check if everything is working. If that works, then reenable security and try to configure it like shown.

Answer (score 0):

From my working project. The resources is under resources/static/js/script.js. And I am accessing it from html like js/script.js. No issue. Probably you are missing static folder. And if you are using spring security, you need to make the resources available.

[image]

Comment: Yes,I'm using spring security. I moved all the folder to static folder under resources. Still it is not loading. It says
Style sheet couldnot be loaded localhost:9000/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css